# FindMinimum/FindRoot failed to converge

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization

I have a function `SQ` where it is also determined by `sig`. For `b=0.1` and `zh=0.1` everything goes well. I plot `sig` and `SQ` to check its behavior for some `zQ` interval. My goal is to find at which `zQ` is `SQ` a minimum.

```
d = 3;
ag = 10;
pg = 10;
wp = 20;
f[z_, zh_] := 1 - (z/zh)^(d + 1);
torootsig[b_?NumericQ, sig_?NumericQ, zQ_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := Module[{br, sigr, zQr, zhr}, {br, sigr, zQr, zhr} = Rationalize[{b, sig, zQ, zh}, 0]; br - NIntegrate[z^d/Sqrt[f[z, zhr] (zQr^(2 d) (1 + (sigr^2/f[zQr, zhr])) - z^(2 d))], {z, 0, zQr}, AccuracyGoal -> ag, PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp, MaxRecursion -> 100]]
sig[b_?NumericQ, zQ_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := sig /. FindRoot[torootsig[b, sig, zQ, zh] == 0, {sig, -2 zh, 0}, AccuracyGoal -> ag, PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp, MaxIterations -> 100]
intSQ1[b_?NumericQ, zQ_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := Module[{br, zQr, zhr}, {br, zQr, zhr} = Rationalize[{b, zQ, zh}, 0]; (-1/(d - 1)) (1/(zQr^(2 d) (1 + sig[br, zQr, zhr]^2/f[zQr, zhr]))) NIntegrate[z^d Sqrt[f[z, zhr]/(1 - (1/(zQr^(2 d) (1 + sig[br, zQr, zhr]^2/f[zQr, zhr]))) z^(2 d))], {z, 0, zQr}, AccuracyGoal -> ag, PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp, MaxRecursion -> 100]]
intSQ2[b_?NumericQ, zQ_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := Module[{br, zQr, zhr}, {br, zQr, zhr} = Rationalize[{b, zQ, zh}, 0]; (-1/(2 zhr^(d + 1))) ((d + 1)/(d - 1)) NIntegrate[z Sqrt[(1 - (1/(zQr^(2 d) (1 + sig[br, zQr, zhr]^2/f[zQr, zhr]))) z^(2 d))/f[z, zhr]], {z, 0, zQr}, AccuracyGoal -> ag, PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp, MaxRecursion -> 100]]
intSQ3[b_?NumericQ, zQ_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := Module[{br, zQr, zhr}, {br, zQr, zhr} = Rationalize[{b, zQ, zh}, 0]; (1/zhr)^(d + 1) NIntegrate[z/Sqrt[f[z, zhr] (1 - (1/(zQr^(2 d) (1 + sig[br, zQr, zhr]^2/f[zQr, zhr]))) z^(2 d))], {z, 0, zQr}, AccuracyGoal -> ag, PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp, MaxRecursion -> 100]]
SQ[b_?NumericQ, zQ_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := Module[{br, zQr, zhr}, {br, zQr, zhr} = Rationalize[{b, zQ, zh}, 0]; (-Sqrt[f[zQr, zhr] (1 - (1/(zQr^(2 d) (1 + sig[br, zQr, zhr]^2/f[zQr, zhr]))) zQr^(2 d))]/((d - 1) zQr^(d - 1)) + intSQ1[br, zQr, zhr] + intSQ2[br, zQr, zhr] + intSQ3[br, zQr, zhr] + 1/zQr^(d - 1))/4 ]

Plot[sig[0.1, zQ, 0.1], {zQ, 0.995 0.1, 0.1}, PlotPoints -> 3, Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 14], FrameLabel -> {"zQ", "sig"}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thickness[0.005]}, PlotRange -> Full, ImageSize -> Large] // AbsoluteTiming

Plot[SQ[0.1, zQ, 0.1], {zQ, 0.995 0.1, 0.9999 0.1}, PlotPoints -> 3, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"zQ", "SQ"}, FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 14], PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thickness[0.005]}, PlotRange -> Full, ImageSize -> Large] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

The minimum of `SQ` is found,

```
FindMinimum[SQ[0.1, zQ, 0.1], {zQ, 0.999 0.1, 0.9999 0.1}, AccuracyGoal -> ag, PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp, MaxIterations -> 20]
{41.70848808, {zQ -> 0.09987512218}}
```

The problem is when I change to `b=0.5`, it becomes harder to plot `sig` and `SQ` so as to estimate the range `zQ` where `SQ` is a minimum. Also, I've tried to check small ranges and another problem is that the plot becomes *not smooth*. In addition, I'm not so sure if it has to do with picking a better initial value in the `FindRoot` but I just took an initial guess.

If it's possible I would also like to see the value at `b=1`.

```
sig[0.5, 0.9999999995 0.1, 0.1]
During evaluation of In[494]:= FindRoot::cvmit: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations.
-8.0900306144401424236*10^-9

SQ[0.5, 0.9999999999728 0.1, 0.1]
FindRoot::cvmit: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations.

Plot[sig[0.5, zQ, 0.1], {zQ, 0.9999999995 0.1, 0.1}, PlotPoints -> 3, Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 14], FrameLabel -> {"zQ", "sig"}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thickness[0.005]}, PlotRange -> Full, ImageSize -> Large] // AbsoluteTiming

Plot[SQ[0.5, zQ, 0.1], {zQ, 0.9999999995 0.1, 0.99999999999 0.1}, PlotPoints -> 3, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"zQ", "SQ"}, FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 14], PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thickness[0.005]}, PlotRange -> Full, ImageSize -> Large] // AbsoluteTiming
```

Any guidance on this?

Comment: Taking into account the response "During evaluation of In[494]:= FindRoot::cvmit: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations.
-8.0900306144401424236*10^-9" (i.e. the minimum value is very small), find minimum of  `Exp[your expression]` and then take `Log` of the result. I don't go into deep of your code.

Comment: @user64494 Isn't `Exp[SQ]` big since `SQ` is big? What exactly do you mean?

Comment: `Plot[sig[0.5, zQ, 0.1], {zQ, 0.9999999995 0.1, 0.1}, PlotPoints -> 3, Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 14], FrameLabel -> {"zQ", "sig"}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thickness[0.005]}, PlotRange -> Full, ImageSize -> Large] // AbsoluteTiming` shows values of order 10^-9. Its exponent is of order one. Hope you feel the difference.

Comment: Also decrease `ag ` and 
`pg` and increase `MaxIterations`. `10` is too many. In most cases `4` is more than enough.

Comment: @user64494 I have increased `MaxIterations->2000` and set `ag=pg=4`. I'm still not sure where to do `Exp[sig]` since I think the problem is with the settings of the functions I guess. But maybe what you mean is `Exp[sig[0.5, 0.9999999995 0.1, 0.1]]`, I chose `0.9999999995*0.1` just as a test value, however, I still get `FindRoot::cvmit: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 2000 iterations. 0.9999999919099703655417828170`

Comment: No, I don't mean " But maybe what you mean is `Exp[sig[0.5, 0.9999999995 0.1, 0.1]]`". I mean that I wrote.

Comment: @user64494 I'm not quite sure what you wanted me to do exactly but I have tried increasing `MaxIterations` and lowering `AccuracyGoal` & `PrecisonGoal`. The result is still problematic. I think as I increase `b`, the range of `zQ` becomes narrower and narrower so it becomes harder to choose good initial points for `FindRoot`. As an example, for `b=0.1` the range `0.0995 < zQ < 1` for `SQ` produces the plot but if I use that same range for `b=0.5` it produces an error.